# Extract Regex Match

Tags: regex, regex-negation, yahoo-pipes

I want to scrape the src of images in a RSS Feed with Yahoo Pipes.

This Regex is selecting exactly what I want.

```
src="([^"]*)"
```

Image: `<img src="image.jpg" width="300" height="422" alt="urkunde300" style="margin-right: 10px;" />`

Pipes: In `scrapedimage` replace `src="([^"]*)"` with `$1`

Output: `<img//// width="300" height="422" alt="image300" style="margin-right:10px;"/>`

How do I invert the Match so I can replace everything except `image.jpg` with 'nothing'

Answer (score 1):

You want to match the whole line (`<img src="([^"]+)".*`), and replace it by specified group in regex (`$1`)

Comment: I forgot to say that the <img> is between some code. But your Regex is already deleting the container aroung image.jpg, but not the complete rest of the code
`<p><strong>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="example.com"><img src="image.jpg" width="300" height="422" alt="urkunde300" style="margin-right:10px;"/></a></td>`

Comment: I got it now:
REPLACE `(.*?)(?=src=)src=\"(.*?)\"(.*)` WITH `$2` (Modifier s)

Comment: I would keep img in the Regex, so that if some other tag has a src attribute (like a <script>), you won't capture it.